# AWS SAM local with AppConfig local development mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

I'm trying to test a Python lambda locally along with the AppConfigAgent lambda extension using the local development mode (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-retrieving-simplified-methods-local-development.html).

Without local development mode I have this working. I can curl my lambda and it looks up the AppConfig from the real AWS environment and provides the results back.

However when running locally for testing I don't want the real AppConfig to be used but instead values from a configuration file (as per the link above).

I've added the environment variable to my `template.yaml` file but it doesn't seem to be picked up.

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_DIRECTORY: "./appconfig"
```

Has anyone got this working?

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding sample output when connecting to the running container:

```
bash-4.2# export | grep AWS_APPCONFIG
declare -x AWS_APPCONFIG_EXTENSION_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_DIRECTORY="/var/task/appconfig"
declare -x AWS_APPCONFIG_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL="debug"
bash-4.2# ls /var/task/appconfig/ -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65 Jan  4 12:15 app:environment:profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65 Jan  4 12:15 app:environment:profile.json
bash-4.2# curl http://localhost:2772/applications/app/environments/environment/configurations/profile
{"Message":"Application not found","ReferencedBy":{"ApplicationIdentifier":"app"},"ResourceType":"Application"}
bash-4.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AWS_APPCONFIG_EXTENSION_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_DIRECTORY` environment variable.

When running the agent in Lambda, environment variables are prefixed with `AWS_APPCONFIG_EXTENSION_` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions.html#appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions-config).

By the way, I work on the AWS AppConfig team. We’ll update our documentation to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried this and it does not work for me.

Comment: Should AppConfigAgent show that it's picked up this location when it runs? I do not see anything noted in the SAM output, even with debug on.

Comment: I've also played around with the path. Setting it to be an absolute path of my local file system, and then a path relative to the Docker container (/var/task/appconfig) and made sure the files are present there but still no joy.

Comment: Which version of the extension are you using? It should be at least version 2.0.358. See [release notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions-versions.html#appconfig-integration-lambda-extensions-versions-release-notes).

Comment: Thanks Ben. That's done it! Not sure why I wasn't using the latest one. Looks like I mixed region account with a wrong version in that region.